# Saving Image to drupal site using drupalgap

Tags: image, drupal-7, save

I am trying to save an image from android emulator to drupal site using drupalgap, but I am unable to do this, below is my ajax call which I wrote to save the data to drupal site.

My AJAX call

```
$.ajax({
              url: "http://192.168.1.146/drunew/?q=my_services/node.json",
              type: 'post',
              data: 'node[type]=drupalgap&node[title]=' + encodeURIComponent(title) + '&node[language]=und&node[body][und][0][value]=' + encodeURIComponent(body) + '&node[files][field_filef_und_0]=' + encodeURIComponent(filef),
              dataType: 'json',
              beforeSend: function (request) {
                        request.setRequestHeader("X-CSRF-Token", token);
                     },
              error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert('page_node_create_submit - failed to login');
                console.log(JSON.stringify(XMLHttpRequest));
                console.log(JSON.stringify(textStatus));
                console.log(JSON.stringify(errorThrown));
              },
              success: function (data) {

               $.mobile.changePage("main.html", "slideup");
              }
          });
```

But the above code is not working for file field, then after doing some R&D I got to know that first we have to get the fid, then save it.

Below is the respone after creating the fid for the image.

```
{"fid":"47","uri":"http://192.168.1.146/drunew/my_services/file/47"}
```

Here my doubt is how can I integrate this response in my above ajax call to save the image in drupal site.

Any help, thanks..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you have the File ID, you pass that along with the Node Create/Update resource like so:

Node Create - POST

```
http://www.example.com/?q=drupalgap/node.json&title=Hello&type=article&field_images[und][0][fid]=47
```

Node Update - PUT

```
http://www.example.com/?q=drupalgap/node/123.json&field_images[und][0][fid]=47
```

FYI, this feature is now built into DrupalGap core, so you shouldn't have to do much when adding/editing nodes.